# Penalties In Soft margin SVM

Tags: svm

In Soft Margin SVM, The Penalty  $\xi_i$ , is given by

$\xi_i = 1- y_i(\omega x_i+b)$ ,  if $x_i$ is on the wrong side of the margin

i.e ($x_i $ is incorrectly Classified)

From where we got this $\xi_i = 1- y_i(\omega x_i+b)$ and How?

Figure for reference

[image]